# Set is keeping old object even after the new insertion

Tags: swift, hashmap, set

All my life I believed, `Set` will replace the existing Value when inserting new Value to maintain it's unique property. But today I am surprised that it's not,

**Code:**

```
enum Action {
    case edit
    case delete
    case update
}
```

---

```
struct Object: Equatable, Hashable {
    let id: String
    let action: Action
    let code: UInt8
    var description: String {
        return "`\(self.action)` on `\(self.id)` with #\(self.code)"
    }
    init(id: String, action: Action, code: UInt8) {
        self.id = id
        self.action = action
        self.code = code
    }
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {   
        hasher.combine(self.id)
    }
    static func == (lhs: Object, rhs: Object) -> Bool {   
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

So I used the property `id` to maintain unique. When I insert new object with same `id` and different other values then the `Set` is kept the old one instead of new insertion.

```
var collection = Set<Object>()
let obj1 = Object(id: "1", action: .delete, code: 1) // `delete` on `1` with #1
collection.insert(obj1) 
let obj2 = Object(id: "1", action: .update, code: 4) // `update` on `1` with #4
collection.insert(obj2)
print(collection.first!.description) // `delete` on `1` with #1
```

---

The print supposed to be for `code: 4` as I thought, but it is `code: 1`. Actually I did used the technique in a `search-hungry` project and lot of places and it's not worked to be expected today, after long debug I did found this.

Is this the way `Set` works in Swift or Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: _"Inserts the given element in the set if it is not already present."_, from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/insert(_:)-nads) that you should perhaps read.

Comment: I would also recommend to go over data collections of swift documentation

Comment: *"All my life I believed, `Set` will replace the existing Value"* - So you're only 9 years old? Wow. :)

Comment: @HangarRash Haha, Yes technically in programming world not only Swift but the device called Computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue there is that you are ignoring the result from the insert method. You should try to insert and if it is not inserted you can update the set. Something like:

```
if !collection.insert(obj2).inserted {
    collection.update(with: obj2)
}
```

Comment: `collection.update(with: obj2)` is inserts even if the collection is empty. if same id exists then it is updating the existing `obj1` to `obj2`. So, I didn't added the `if !collection.insert(obj2).inserted {` condition instead just go with `collection.update(with: obj2)` . Is there any issue?

Comment: Thats fine update `Inserts the given element into the set unconditionally.` If you don't need to know if the object already exists you can simply use update.